# Extend a form from a custom module

Tags: forms, hooks

I'm newbie with Drupal 8. I was entrusted with hanging a custom module to a Drupal 8 default login form.

> [image: screenshot]

Together with these fields, I would like to see those of my form, which should be generated in this way.

```
use Drupal\trust_ppg\Consents;

function hooks_enabled()
{
    $value = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_module_checkbox_value');
    if ($value == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(). - REGISTRATION form
function trust_ppg_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    if (hooks_enabled() == false) {
        return $form;
    }
    $account = $form['#user'];
    $form = array_merge($form, trust_ppg_policies_form($account));
    $form['#validate'][] = 'registration_extra_fields_validate';
}

// Implements hook_validate(). FIXME -> move to formbuilder
function registration_extra_fields_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
    if (hooks_enabled() == false) {
        return;
    }
    $error_messages = [];
    if ($form_state['input']['tou'] != '1') {
        $error_messages["body"][] = 'In order to proceed with the registration you need to accept the Terms Of Use!';
    }
    if ($form_state['input']['privacy_policy'] != '1') {
        $error_messages["body"][] = 'In order to proceed with the registration you need to accept the Privacy Policy!';
    }
    if ($form_state['input']['cookie_policy'] != '1') {
        $error_messages["body"][] = 'In order to proceed with the registration you need to accept the Cookie Policy!';
    }
    // Add new mandatory policies here
    foreach ($error_messages as $element => $messages) {
        // FIXME - form_set_error($element, theme('item_list', array('items' => $messages)));
    }
}

// Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(). - USER PROFILE form
function trust_ppg_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state)
{
    if (hooks_enabled() == false || $form['#user_category'] != 'account') {
        return $form;
    }
    $account = $form['#user'];
    $form = array_merge($form, trust_ppg_policies_form($account));
}

// Implements hook_help().
function trust_ppg_help($path, $arg)
{
    switch ($path) {
        case "admin/help#trust_ppg":
            return t("Help Hook");
            break;
    }
}

// Implements hook_cron().
function trust_ppg_cron()
{
    Consents::process_consents_batch();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert().
 * - A user account was created.
 *
 * @FIXME
 * The $edit and $category parameters are gone in Drupal 8. They have been left
 * here in order to prevent 'undefined variable' errors, but they will never
 * actually be passed to this hook. You'll need to modify this function and
 * remove every reference to them.
 */

function trust_ppg_user_insert(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $account, $category, $edit = null)
{
    $tou_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_tou_guid_value');
    if ($tou_guid != 0) {
        $tou_consent = $edit['tou'];
        if ($tou_consent == 1) {
            give_consent_user($tou_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $privacy_policy_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_privacy_policy_guid_value');
    if ($privacy_policy_guid != 0) {
        $privacy_consent = $edit['privacy_policy'];
        if ($privacy_consent == 1) {
            give_consent_user($privacy_policy_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $cookie_policy_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_policy_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_policy_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_consent = $edit['cookie_policy'];
        if ($cookie_consent == 1) {
            give_consent_user($cookie_policy_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $cookie_policy_3rdparties_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_3rdparties_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_policy_3rdparties_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_3rdparties_consent = $edit['cookie_3rdparties'];
        if ($cookie_3rdparties_consent == 1) {
            give_consent_user($cookie_policy_3rdparties_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $cookie_policy_additional_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_additional_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_policy_additional_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_additional_consent = $edit['cookie_additional'];
        if ($cookie_additional_consent == 1) {
            give_consent_user($cookie_policy_additional_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $marketing_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_marketing_guid_value');
    if ($marketing_guid != 0) {
        $marketing = $edit['marketing'];
        if ($marketing == 1) {
            give_consent_user($marketing_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $db_publication_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_db_publication_guid_value');
    if ($db_publication_guid != 0) {
        $db_publication = $edit['db_publication'];
        if ($db_publication == 1) {
            give_consent_user($db_publication_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $soft_optin_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_soft_optin_guid_value');
    if ($soft_optin_guid != 0) {
        $soft_optin = $edit['soft_optin'];
        if ($soft_optin == 1) {
            give_consent_user($soft_optin_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $profiling_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_profiling_guid_value');
    if ($profiling_guid != 0) {
        $profiling = $edit['profiling'];
        if ($profiling == 1) {
            give_consent_user($profiling_guid, $account);
        }
    }

    $newsletter_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_newsletter_guid_value');
    if ($newsletter_guid != 0) {
        $newsletter = $edit['newsletter'];
        if ($newsletter == 1) {
            give_consent_user($newsletter_guid, $account);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_update().
 *
 * @FIXME
 * The $edit and $category parameters are gone in Drupal 8. They have been left
 * here in order to prevent 'undefined variable' errors, but they will never
 * actually be passed to this hook. You'll need to modify this function and
 * remove every reference to them.
 */
function trust_ppg_user_update(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $account, $category, $edit = null)
{
    $tou_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_tou_guid_value');
    if ($tou_guid != 0) {
        $tou_consent = $edit['tou'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($tou_consent, $tou_guid, $account);
    }

    $privacy_policy_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_privacy_policy_guid_value');
    if ($privacy_policy_guid != 0) {
        $privacy_consent = $edit['privacy_policy'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($privacy_consent, $privacy_policy_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_policy_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_consent = $edit['cookie_policy'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_consent, $cookie_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_3rdparties_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_3rdparties_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_3rdparties_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_3rdparties_consent = $edit['cookie_3rdparties'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_3rdparties_consent, $cookie_3rdparties_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_additional_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_additional_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_additional_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_additional_consent = $edit['cookie_additional'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_additional_consent, $cookie_additional_guid, $account);
    }

    //
    $marketing_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_marketing_guid_value');
    if ($marketing_guid != 0) {
        $marketing = $edit['marketing'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($marketing, $marketing_guid, $account);
    }

    $db_publication_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_db_publication_guid_value');
    if ($db_publication_guid != 0) {
        $db_publication = $edit['db_publication'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($db_publication, $db_publication_guid, $account);
    }

    $soft_optin_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_soft_optin_guid_value');
    if ($soft_optin_guid != 0) {
        $soft_optin = $edit['soft_optin'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($soft_optin, $soft_optin_guid, $account);
    }

    $profiling_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_profiling_guid_value');
    if ($profiling_guid != 0) {
        $profiling = $edit['profiling'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($profiling, $profiling_guid, $account);
    }

    $newsletter_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_newsletter_guid_value');
    if ($newsletter_guid != 0) {
        $newsletter = $edit['newsletter'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($newsletter, $newsletter_guid, $account);
    }
    // Add new entries here
}

function _expose_var(&$build, $var_name, $var)
{
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings'][$var_name] = $var;
}

//Implements hook_preprocess_page(). - useful to force redirect, for example
function trust_ppg_page_attachments(array &$page)
{
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

    _expose_var($page, 'ga_guid', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_ga_guid'));

    /* If you change the default text remember to change all occurences */
    _expose_var($page, 'main_text', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_text'));
    _expose_var($page, 'policy_label', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_label'));

    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
        $cookie_policy_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_policy_guid_value');
        $consent = Consents::get_consent($cookie_policy_guid, $user);

        $cookie_policy_3rdparties_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_3rdparties_guid_value');
        $consent_3rdparties = Consents::get_consent($cookie_policy_3rdparties_guid, $user);

        $cookie_policy_additional_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_additional_guid_value');
        $consent_additional = Consents::get_consent($cookie_policy_additional_guid, $user);
        // Add mandatory policies here

        // Expose variables for JS
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_3rdparties_consent', is_array($consent_3rdparties));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_additional_consent', is_array($consent_additional));
        _expose_var($page, 'username', $user->getAccountName());
    } else {
        // Expose policies GUIDs
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_policy', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_policy_guid_value'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_3rdparties', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_3rdparties_guid_value'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_additional', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_additional_guid_value'));

        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_policy_label', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_policy_label'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_3rdparties_label', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_3rdparties_label'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_additional_label', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_additional_label'));

        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_policy_body', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_policy_body'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_3rdparties_body', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_3rdparties_body'));
        _expose_var($page, 'cookie_additional_body', \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_popup_cookie_additional_body'));

        if (isset($_COOKIE['consent_3rdparties_cookies']) && isset($_COOKIE['consent_additional_cookies'])) {
            _expose_var($page, 'cookie_3rdparties_consent', $_COOKIE['consent_3rdparties_cookies']);
            _expose_var($page, 'cookie_additional_consent', $_COOKIE['consent_additional_cookies']);
        }
    }

    if (hooks_enabled()) {
        $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'trust_ppg/main';
        //redirect_to_consent('');

        //POPUP
        if (
            \Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()
            && \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() != '/privacy-policy-full'
            && \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() != '/user'
            && \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() != '/user/register'
            && \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() != '/company/register'
            && \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() != '/research/register'
        ) {
            dpm('popup');
            $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'trust_ppg/modal';
            $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'trust_ppg/disabler';
            dpm($page, '$page');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 *
 * @param string $op
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
 *      The operation to be performed. Possible values:
 *          "create"
 *          "delete"
 *          "update"
 *          "view"
 * @param string $node
 *         Either a node object or the machine name of the
 *        content type on which to perform the access check.
 * @param object $user
 *
 * @return constant
 *        NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW, NODE_ACCESS_DENY, NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE
 */
function trust_ppg_access($op, $node, $account)
{
    return ($op == 'view' && ($account->hasPermission('permission ro') || $account->hasPermission('administer trust_ppg')));
}

// Implements hook_theme().
function trust_ppg_theme()
{
    return array();
}

function trust_ppg_policies_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    if (\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("<current>")->toString() == 'privacy-policy-full') {
        $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
        $account = $user;
    } else {
        $account = $form['#user'];
    }

    $tou_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_tou_guid_value');
    if ($tou_guid != 0) {
        $tou_consent = $form_state['input']['tou'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($tou_consent, $tou_guid, $account);
    }

    $privacy_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_privacy_policy_guid_value');
    if ($privacy_guid != 0) {
        $privacy_consent = $form_state['input']['privacy_policy'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($privacy_consent, $privacy_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_policy_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_consent = $form_state['input']['cookie_policy'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_consent, $cookie_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_3rdparties_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_3rdparties_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_3rdparties_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_3rdparties_consent = $form_state['input']['cookie_3rdparties'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_3rdparties_consent, $cookie_3rdparties_guid, $account);
    }

    $cookie_additional_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_cookie_additional_guid_value');
    if ($cookie_additional_guid != 0) {
        $cookie_additional_consent = $form_state['input']['cookie_additional'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($cookie_additional_consent, $cookie_additional_guid, $account);
    }
    //
    $marketing_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_marketing_guid_value');
    if ($marketing_guid != 0) {
        $marketing = $form_state['input']['marketing'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($marketing, $marketing_guid, $account);
    }

    $db_publication_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_db_publication_guid_value');
    if ($db_publication_guid != 0) {
        $db_publication = $form_state['input']['db_publication'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($db_publication, $db_publication_guid, $account);
    }

    $soft_optin_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_soft_optin_guid_value');
    if ($soft_optin_guid != 0) {
        $soft_optin = $form_state['input']['soft_optin'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($soft_optin, $soft_optin_guid, $account);
    }

    $profiling_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_profiling_guid_value');
    if ($profiling_guid != 0) {
        $profiling = $form_state['input']['profiling'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($profiling, $profiling_guid, $account);
    }

    $newsletter_guid = \Drupal::config('trust_ppg.settings')->get('trust_ppg_newsletter_guid_value');
    if ($newsletter_guid != 0) {
        $newsletter = $form_state['input']['newsletter'];
        manage_consent_wrapper($newsletter, $newsletter_guid, $account);
    }
}
```

How do I create an alleged hook (in Drupal 7 hooks were used, I think maybe they should also be used in Drupal 8) that allows me to add my module to the default form of Drupal 8?

Comment: As side note, there are at least four errors in the code: `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementations don't return any value, not even the form, since that is passed by reference; it's not true that a `hook_user_insert()` implementation needs to define `$edit` and `$category` as parameters; a `hook_user_insert()` implementation takes the account values from `$account`, the first argument the hook gets; functions defined from a module must be prefixed from its machine name, so a function name like `hook_enabled()` or `registration_extra_fields_validate()` is wrong.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'll fix the code right away.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I edited the question starting from the working and hooked form in drupal 7. Rather than asking another question, I preferred to edit this (I don't know if I did well). Let me know an opinion. However, the edits can still be consulted.

Comment: Once the question gets answers, it cannot be edited, if the edits invalidate any given answer. If you have a new question, ask it. Questions aren't though as back-and-forth with the users who answer, nor to be re-used to ask a different question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

As start, the code shown in the question is wrong in many points, in particular because it is using Drupal 7 code that has not been converted to Drupal 8. Drupal core has modules that alter the user edit form, which could be taken as guide for your own code.

Since you want to alter the user edit form when users create an account and when an existing account is edited, you should look at [`contact_form_user_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21contact%21contact.module/function/contact_form_user_form_alter/8.8.x), which is used for exactly those two forms. From that hook implementation, and the code in [`AccountForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21AccountForm.php/function/AccountForm%3A%3Aform/8.8.x), you will notice that:

- `#user_category` isn't used anymore
- The user account being edit isn't given anymore in `$form['#user']` but it can be retrieved with `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()`
- The user editing that account, useful to determine who is editing the account, or to check if somebody is registering an account, can be retrieved with `\Drupal::currentUser()`
- Any submission handler for the button used to create the account or edit it is added with `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]`, while a validation handler is added with `$form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][]`

As for the form submission and validation handlers:

- `$form_state` isn't anymore an array, but it's an object implementing the [`FormStateInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/interface/FormStateInterface/8.8.x) interface
- The values submitted in a form element are given from  [`$form_state->getValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AgetValue/8.8.x)
- In case of validation errors, those errors are added using [`$form_state->setErrorByName()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8.8.x) or [`$form_state->setError()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetError/8.8.x)

In some cases, it can be helpful to understand if a hook implementation like `contact_form_user_form_alter()` is invoked when people registers their own account, an administrator is creating an account for somebody else, or an account is edited. In those cases, the following code can be helpful.

```
$account = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$register = $account->isAnonymous();
$admin_create = $register && $account->access('create');
$self_register = $register && !$admin_create;
```

Using that code, `$register` is `TRUE` if an account is being registered/created, or `FALSE` if an existing account is edited; `$admin_create` is `TRUE` if the account is being created from an administrator user; `$self_register` is `TRUE` when the account is being registered.

As for the `hook_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)` and `hook_user_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)` hooks (which are documented as [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.8.x) and [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.8.x)), they only receive an argument: The user object being inserted or updated. Any information about the user needs to be taken from that argument, which is the user object after it has been edited/created. For `hook_user_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)`, `$entity->original` returns the user object before it was changed.

As side note, any function implemented by a module should be prefixed by its machine name, to avoid conflicts with other modules. (The functions of all the modules are global.)
You have a `hooks_enabled()` function that could create name clashes with the [Hooks](https://www.drupal.org/project/hooks) module, when it adds a `hooks_enabled()` function to its code. You have also a `registration_extra_fields_validate()` function whose name starts with the machine name of the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module.